# HTML to PDF conversion using iTextSharp.dll

Tags: c#, itext

I am converting HTML pages to PDF file format using itextsharp.dll in C#. I am reading the contents from the HTML pages and adding dynamically to PDF file. When I am adding the data to PDF file I need to check the following scenario.

Case 1: When should I add new page to PDF document as i am unable to get the current position of the PDF writing cursor?

Case 2: HTML file can be made up of multiple pages in single file. How can i decide its splitting while adding to PDF file.

Code for above issues would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Case 1 : New pages are added automatically with iText. You can force a new page by using [Document#newPage()](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Document.html#newPage%28%29). Please note that this link points to the Java API, but it's pretty much the same in iTextSharp.

Case 2 : What do you mean by *HTML file can be made up of multiple pages in single file*?